# Use sass variables into js files create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, icss

I have some color defined variables into `_colors.scss` file.

```
$color-succcess: #706caa;
$color-error: #dc3545;
```

I would like to also use them into some styled react components `react-table` into my js file.

I used the following article https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript as reference and many others like it but I cannot get it to work.

I export the colors from my scss file:

```
:export {
  colorSuccess: $color-succcess;
  colorError: $color-error;
}
```

and I import them into my js file:

`import colors from "../../styles/_colors.scss";`

but they are probably not loaded right.

How can I configure the create-react-app generated code to achieve the same thing as the guy in the article does with webpack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get SCSS variables into react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119188/how-to-get-scss-variables-into-react)

Answer (score 6):

I have faced a similar issue, and it took me a bunch of tries to get the desired result. If you already have `node-sass` installed, try the following.

1. First of all, try importing the main `scss` file without the underscore, i.e. instead of `../../styles/_colors.scss`, try `../../styles/index.scss` or whatewer your main file is.
2. Secondly, keep track of the variable names. This code DID NOT work:

```
:export {
  $textBlack: $text-black;
}
```

while this one works perfectly

```
:export {
  textBlack: $text-black;
}
```

For some reason it does not like the dollar sign in the variable name, though it is a valid JS variable name. Your case should work fine

Answer (score 2):

Try to reproduce these steps:

#### 1. Enable sass in CRA by installing node-sass.

```
npm i --save-dev node-sass
```

#### 2. Create a sass file `example.scss`.

```
$hello: 'world';

:export {
  my-var: $hello;
}
```

#### 3. Import the sass into your react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Example from './example.scss';

export default () => Example.hello;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CRA version 4, there is a known issue where this feature will not work unless you define your scss file as <name>.modules.css.

See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10047#issuecomment-724227353 for details.

Answer (score 0):

install the sass in the project if you didn't install that.

```
yarn add --dev node-sass
```

create a file and use this rule to name it => **filename.module.scss** ( for example variables.module.scss )

```
$color-succcess: #706caa;
$color-error: #dc3545;

:export {
  colorSuccess: $color-succcess;
  colorError: $color-error;
  otherColor: #786539;
}
```

and import it in the component like below:

```
import colors from "../../styles/_colors.module.scss";

const TheComponent = () => {
   console.log(colors.colorSuccess)

   return <h1>The Component</h1>
}

export default TheComponent

// output in console : #706caa
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to load SCSS files in CRA you need to add `node-sass` as your dependency to package.json. I've tested it out and after adding it to clean CRA project and importing `colors` object (using `:export`, like in the code you provided) works as expected.

Comment: This is not working by default. Perhaps additional configuration is required?