# How to get SCSS variables into react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, icss

I followed this post [How to use SCSS variables into my React components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52900207/7462275) or this one [React and SCSS export a variable from scss to react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61460529/7462275) to get scss variable in my react app but it does not work.
**myvar.scss** file:

```
$color: red;

:export {
    color: $color;
}

.myclass {
  background-color: $color;
}
```

**App.js** file:

```
import variables from './myvar.scss';

const App = () => {
    console.log(variables);
    return <div className="myclass">Hello</div>
}

export default App;
```

The div background is red, so myvar.scss is working. But `variables` is an empty object.

(react version : 17.0.1)

node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  strictExportPresence: true,
  rules: [
    { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
    {
      oneOf: [
...
        {
          test: sassRegex,
          exclude: sassModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders(
            {
              importLoaders: 3,
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                ? shouldUseSourceMap
                : isEnvDevelopment,
            },
            'sass-loader'
          ),
          sideEffects: true,
        },
```

Comment: I am facing a similar situation, but I am trying to get an ENV variable into my scss file, can you give a hint?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The original answer claims that it is only supported by webpack, but this is no longer true. Many bundlers now support this via their own css processing pipeline.

**Original Answer**:
That's a webpack/css-loader feature and only works with webpack and css-loader (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#separating-interoperable-css-only-and-css-module-features)

Important: the `:export` syntax in your SCSS/CSS files will only work for those files that are treated as a [module](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules) by css-loader, because this syntax is part of a [css module proposal](https://github.com/css-modules/icss#export).
You can...

- either use the default behavior of css-loader and trigger that behavior via filename: e.g. `foostyle.module.scss`
- or you can configure css-loader to treat all files as modules e.g. `loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true }`

A blogpost with an example can be found here: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript
(Be aware that the blogpost doesn't mention the fact that css modules must be used.)

```
$white-color: #fcf5ed;

:export {
  whitecolor: $white-color;
}
```

and

```
import variables from 'variables.module.scss';

console.log(variables.whitecolor)
```

your webpack.config.js will probably contain a chain of loaders with `css-loader` as last or second-to-last (process-chronologically speaking) and this should work.

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ],
      },
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited my post and I added webpack.config.js

Comment: The problem is only the file name : `variables.module.scss` because of the css-loader default rule `:/\.module\.\w+$/i.test(filename)` (same problem than in the other post). Would you mind editing your answer and adding this point ?

Comment: @Stef1611 I added the css module issue to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say try using like this

```
  const App = () => {
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({
    fontFamily: ''
  });
  return (
    <div style={setParameters(fontFamily && { fontType: 'font_name' })}>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Hope this works for you.