# How to get SCSS variables in js code (nodejs server)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, sass, icss

From this blogpost example https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript, I tried to get scss variables in my js code and I did not manage to do it.

**index.js** file

```
import variables from './variables.scss';
console.log(variables);
```

**variables.scss** file

```
$myvar: 100;

:export {
  myvar: $myvar;
}
```

**webpack.config.js** file

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader'
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader'
        }]
    }]
  }
};
```

*dependencies* in **package.json** file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.21.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
```

Compilation : `npx webpack`
Output :

```
asset main.js 17.2 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)  
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules  
cacheable modules 9.23 KiB  
  modules by path ./src/ 1020 bytes  
    ./src/index.js 324 bytes [built] [code generated]  
    ./src/variables.scss 371 bytes [built] [code generated]  
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/variables.scss 325 bytes [built] [code generated]  
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 8.23 KiB  
    ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]  
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]  
webpack 5.21.2 compiled successfully in 503 ms
```

In the web console, the object `variables` is empty and of course, I could not use `variables.myvar`.
Is there a configuration problem in webpack.config.js ? I tried to simplify it as much as possible. All node_modules are up to date and npm version is 6.14.9.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware of it but maybe this only works for "css modules". I never tried it without having css-loader configured to be module based. (you can see in my config in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120027/1280867) that modules are activated)
Please try the following: rename your `variables.scss` into `variables.module.scss`
Because by default the css-loader will treat your files as modules or not as modules based on the filename (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am learning webpack and its configuration. Before, I let nodejs/react do it for me. But it does not work. In your configuration file, in the post css loader, option{ config no longer exists , you must use postcssoptions. But it still does not work. Another config pb.

Comment: you don't need the postcss-loader. I only use it to add fallback values for css custom properties

Comment: I will try without it when I finish my webpack tutorials. I am aware that I need to have a better understanding of webpack and its modules. Thanks a lot for help. I come back soon.

Comment: You were right. It works only for css module. After some webpack tutorials, I understand your answer. It works. I add `modules:true` in css-loader options and I can get myvar : `variables.local.myvar`. Thanks a lot.