# How to import scss in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am trying to import `.scss` file in a react component.
`import colors from './../../colors.scss'`

The `colors` is `undefined` after I updated the project dependencies.
I've used `node-sass`, `css-loader`, `mini-css-extract-plugin`, `sass-loader`, `style-loader` and `postcss-loader` in my `webpack.config.js`

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
        exclude: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
        include: [config.srcDir],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
      },
    ],
 }
```

Any idea what is missing or something that can be replaced to import scss styles as a value and access it in a react component, like

```
const parentClass = classNames(
    'avatar-font',
    `avatar-font--${avatarProps.size}`,
    bgColor && colors[`bg-color--${ bgColor }`]
  )

return <div className={ parentClass }></div>
```

Current lib versions are,

```
    "webpack": "^5.77.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.2.4",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
```

Comment: Why two rule entries for `test: /\.scss$/`?

Comment: @morganney not sure. old codebase. probably to separate hthe `exclude` and `include`. any idea on why am i getting undefined?

Comment: What is exported in `colors.scss`? How do you import and use it? (That is not shown in your post.) I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120027/1280867) awhile ago that should cover how to share values from SCSS with js code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two rules that cover SCSS, but the second rule configures the `css-loader` differently.

An Explanation:
Exports and imports to share values from CSS/SCSS with the js code are a feature of `css-loader`. At some point in time css-loader behavior changed to only support exports from files that are treated as modules (before that exports worked in all css files).
By default only files that are named `*.module.(s)css` are treated as modules.
But with the config setting `options: { modules: true }` all files are treated as modules.
So if your second rule (that uses the default setting for css-loader) is used to process `colors.scss` the exports won't work.

Add the css-loader config to your second scss rule:

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
      },
```